# What is the meaning of Implicit Authentication?

Tags: authentication

I'm developing a plugin for login in my site. During search for that I see the line below:

```
Implicit Authentication plugins implement support for authenticating users based on http headers.
```

Would you explain its meaning for me ?

Is login using openID an implicit authentication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been already answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/what-is-implicit-authentication). To what I understood implicit authentication is authenticating with a token. And the system cannot be sure the authenticated person ever held the token (in the answer of the link the token is the symmetric key).

To give another example, as far as I understood implicit authentication, authenticating with different accounts is implicit authentication. I.e. you create a Skype account (with username/password) and connect your facebook profile to it. Now when you authenticate to facebook you are implicitly authenticated to skype too.

Just a remark to your line: The http-headers would then transport the token (as session id or anything else)

To complete my answer to your post: Yes openID is also implicit authentication. By explicitly authenticating to openID, you are implicitly authenticated to all other sites registred at openID

Comment: Yes, openID is also implicit authentication